# How to sort a javascript table (ascending or descending) which is the result of some SQL operated table?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I had created a table using JavaScript in which there are three columns Event ID, Events and Total Count. Now I have to sort the third column i.e total count in descending order. I have been looking online how to sort it. I know how to sort tables for standard HTML table `("order": [[ 2, "desc" ]])` but this table is formed using JavaScript, so I am confuse. I could use a loop for creating a table backward i.e  `for(var i=to; i>=from; i--)` but my result JS table is the result from the table which is generated from SQL in which "Events" are not order by ascending or descending. In other words, I am creating this JavaScript table from the SQL generated table. Below is the code I am working on:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        CreateTable(GetSum('#displaytable'));
    });

    function GetSum(tableIdWithHash) {
        var Sum = [];
        var EventIds = [];
        var EventName = [];
        var Data = [];

        $(tableIdWithHash).find('.eventCounts').each(function(i){
        var Counte = $(this).html();
        var Ide = $(this).siblings('.Idevent').html();
        var eName = $(this).siblings('.eventNames').html();

            allSum.sort(function(a,b){
      if(a.eCount > b.eCount){
         return 1;
      } else if (a.eCount < b.eCount){
         return -1;
      } else{
         return 0;
      }
    }); 
        if (EventIds.indexOf(Ide) === -1) {
            EventIds.push(Ide);
            EventName.push(eName);
        }

        var index = EventIds.indexOf(Ide);
        if (Sum[index] == undefined) {
            Sum[index] = Number(Counte);
        }
        else {
            Sum[index] += Number(Counte);
        }
        });

        Data.push(EventIds);
        Data.push(EventName);
        Data.push(Sum);
        //"order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]
        return Data;
    }       
</script>
```

Comment: I've recommended the SQL-Server tag be removed.  SQL Server solutions won't solve JavaScript problems.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to sort (ORDER BY) and sum (OVER()) using SQL Server instead of putting the load on the client

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, there's valid reasons to sort and sum on the server, OR on the client.  One size does not fit all.  That said, if you do it on the client, I think you want to sort and shape your data first, and *then* build the table; don't do it all at once.

Comment: @Paul : So it is not possible to sort records in JavaScript? I could sort data first and use JavaScript to build data but my source table to create this result table is sorted by different column.

Comment: @vicstat I didn't say that. I said it was better to sort your data structure than to try and sort the data while building the table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your actual data in the question, so I'll make the assumption that it looks something like this:

```
var data = [{eventId:1, eventName:'Fish fry', totalCount:5},...]; // where the ... indicates more records of that shape
```

Ok, given that structure, you can use `Array.prototype.sort()` to sort the data before writing it to a table:

```
data.sort(function(a,b){
  if(a.totalCount > b.totalCount){
     return 1;
  } else if (a.totalCount < b.totalCount{
     return -1;
  } else{
     return 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: When I implemented above code ( and also added in the original question above ), it gave me NAN error.  I checked out ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort ) this link. I am not being able to solve this issue.

Comment: Then check the types in your eCount variable.  If it can't be evaluated using GT or LT operators, you'll get that error.